# Location of log for failing definition of azure function triggers

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am quite new to azure functions and have the following problem:
Where can I find the log of failing trigger definitions.

In the code below the setting of the locale fails on azure, but runs without an error on my local machine.
When deploying the code to azure, everything seems to work fine, but i do not have any triggers defined.

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

import locale

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'German') # This fails

@app.route(route="http_trigger1")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Do some work
    # locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'German') # This fails also but I can see it in the corresponding log  of the request
    pass
```

The error/bug is that I cannot see any http_trigger when inspecting the Azure function via the portal.

It was some effort to find the issue of the non-defined triggers, so I used a workaround by setting the locale in a function (see in code above). There I was able to see the log in azure. To prevent this kind of error in the future, I want to know what is the recommend way to find this kind of deployment error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to see the function logs (success, failure) in function app then create application insight instance while creating the Function App.

[image]

I have modified the function code and it worked for me

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import locale

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    logging.info('Locale from environment: %s',locale.getlocale())
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
        )
```

**Local output**-

[image]

> I want to know what is the recommend way to find this kind of deployment error.

If you are deploying using vs code then you can see the deployment error or successful completion as shown below-

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Portal**-

[image]

[image]

**You can see the logs in Monitor Blade**.

[image]

In the same way, you can use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'German')` in the function.